# Does inner class need to be patched within outer?

Tags: java, javac, inner-classes, nested-class

I have parent class with some method `doIt(...)` and several inner classes. I have changed implementation of this method. Method signature left unchanged. Logic of that class is overcomplicated and I have no time to find out the call stack. After rebuilding project I see parent and its inner classes class files were recompiled. Now I need to patch system with updated ones. The question is does inner class also need to be a part of patch if actually only parent method implementation was changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you re-compile a `*.java` file all the classes are produced whether you changed just one class or all of them.

If you changed just the code of one inner class, that is all you need to patch.  IMHO, I wouldn't take the chance and I would patch the whole lot as there is very little disadvantage in doing so generally.

Comment: Thanks and take a vote. Actually I need to be sure that inner classes class files are compatible anyway if only parent class class file has unrelated changes.

Answer (score 0):

Actually only changed classes should be patched. For my case it's an outer one. So the answer is: no, only outer class where changes were implemented should be patched.